# Как получить данные прогресса загрузки при использовании команды os.system с командой git clone

Tags: python

Как получить данные прогресса загрузки при использовании команды os.system с командой git clone...

Что типа вроде этого:

```
import subprocess

batcmd = "git clone https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/PyConversations.git"
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
print(result)
```

Однако result возвращает **b' '**. Это если мы используем команду **git clone...**

А, например

```
import subprocess

batcmd = "ls"
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
print(result)
```

вернет не пустую строку с именами директорий и файлов.

А хотелось бы знать, как получить стандартный вывод при использовании команды **git clone...**:

```
...
Receiving objects:  31% (783/2524), 4.14 MiB | 611.00 KiB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что git выводит отчёты не в поток вывода, а в поток ошибок. Поэтому нужно либо перехватывать и поток ошибок

```
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

либо передать git ключ, изменяющий поток вывода

```
batcmd = "git clone --progress https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/PyConversations.git"
```