# Как в рантайме отследить результат от subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python-3.x

Как в рантайме отследить результат от subprocess.check_output? Есть приблизительный код, который демонстрирует то, что я хочу получить, а именно: запустить процесс клонирования репозитория и выводить пользователю результат этого процесса:

```
import threading
import subprocess

result = None


def check_progress():
    while True:
        if result:
            print(result.decode('u8').split('\n'))
            break

batcmd = \
    "git clone --progress https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/PyConversations.git"
threading.Thread(target=check_progress, args=()).start()
result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Однако, переменная result получит свое значение только тогда, когда завершится операция **git clone --progress https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/PyConversations.git**, что естественно, никуда не годится! Как в рантайме отследить результат от subprocess.check_output?

Связанный вопрос - [Как получить данные прогресса загрузки при использовании команды os.system с командой git clone](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952925/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-os-system-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: Вам не помог мой ответ на ваш прошлый вопрос или вы сознательно игнорируете [правила ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) и не отмечаете решения?

Comment: Извините, но ваше Ваше решение не правильное!

Comment: Тем не менее в этом вопросе вы именно его и используете.

Comment: Как только мы найдем решение проблемы, я приму ваш ответ. Пока он не дает ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

CONSOLE_ENCODING = 'cp866'  # Укажите здесь кодировку вашей консоли

cmd = [
    'git',
    'clone',
    '--progress',
    'https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/PyConversations.git',
]

p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line.decode(CONSOLE_ENCODING), end='')
```

Comment: Пока Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)  не завершится никакой код выполнен не будет!

Comment: Если это действительно так, то зачем нужен метод [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)?

Comment: @Xyanight попробуйте выполнить [этот скрипт](https://gist.github.com/TheDeadOne/3f76f02ac220989347de481db593115a). Сообщение "Я выполняюсь" вы увидите раньше, чем через 3 секунду, которые будет выполняться ping.

Comment: Да, это верно, но с командой git clone это не проходит. Цикл выполняется только после завершения команды git clone.

Comment: Это значит, что сам git буферизирует свой выходной поток и отдаёт его только одним куском. С этим вы ничего не сможете сделать.

Comment: Я уже это понял и использую ссылки для скачивания репы вида https://codeload.github.com/User/Repo/zip/master, чтобы отображать процесс загрузки.